# Bulk trim videos : remove last x seconds from video

Tags: ffmpeg, trim, bulk

Hey guys i have been searching for hours but this is giving me a lot of trouble. None of the code i found worked for me.

I have a lot of videos with a different length where i want to bulk remove the last 5 second outro of. Sadly it seems that this is almost impossible as I tried it with FFMPEG -sseof command but that needs to have the actual video length, and all my videos have a different length. Is there any easy way to do this and have the videos output in a new folder trimmed folder in the original folder?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with a single ffmpeg call. It must be done in a script with a pair of ffprobe and ffmpeg calls.

Calling

```
ffprobe -of default=nk=1:nw=1 -show_entries format=duration url
```

returns the duration in seconds in `stdout`. Capture it (& convert it to a number) then use it to formulate your ffmpeg expression.